# get details of the classname of an element in the onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

i am having a div element with two onClick events one for the main div and second for an image inside the div.I need to segregate the click based on the event property so far i have tried e.target.nodeName which only gives me the type of html element ie 'DIV' or 'IMG' but in my scenario i am adding two or more images/icons  in the same div and make it do action based on Onclick event.Is there a way to get the details inside the element like className in the case of an image the alt value etc in Onclick event?

my code is as follows

```
{ imageGalley&&<><img className="Images_galley" src={imageGalley}  alt='Galley'/>
          {
          galleyBoxes
          .map((_,index) => {
          return (
            <>
          <div id={_.id} class="ImageArea"
          onClick={(e)=>onClickBox(e,_.id)}  //the onClick of the main div
          style={{
          width: _.width,
          height: _.height,
          bottom: _.bottom,
          left: _.left,
          overflowY:'auto'
          }}
          >
          <img className="galley-icons" src={galleyLabel} onClick={()=>setTextBox({id:_.id,show:!textBox.show})}  alt='galleyLabel'/>
         { textBox.id===_.id&&textBox.show&&<input
          id={''}
          name='carrierCode'
          onChange={(e)=>onChangeBoxName(e,_.id)}
          value={_.name}
          type={'text'}
          className='edit-input'
          />}
          {boxes.map((item,index) => {
          if(item.id === _.id&& item.index===(initTab||galleyIndex)){
          return (<>
             <div className='galley_box flexRow' key={index}>
            <span><b style={{outline:"1px solid",padding:'3px',top: 5,zIndex: 1,position:'sticky',backgroundColor:'#bebebe'
          }}>{item.trolleyNo}</b>
          <u style={{outline:"1px none",padding:'3px',top: 5,zIndex: 1,position:'sticky',backgroundColor:'#bebebe',marginLeft:'1rem',whiteSpace:'nowrap'
          }}>{getCartType(item.cartType)}</u></span>
          <img className="galley-icons" src={plus}  alt='Galley'/><img className="galley-icons" src={editGalleyItem}  alt='Galley'/><br/>
          </div>
          {getTrolleyItems(item.trolleyItems)}
          </>
          )
          }
          return null;
          }
          )}
          
          </div></>
          )
          })
     
          }
          </>
          }
```

my onClick function

```
const onClickBox=(e,id)=>{
    console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",e.target)
      setShowAddTrolley({trolleyNo:id});
      const galleyObj=boxes.find(b=>b.id===id);
      if(galleyObj){
      setEditgalley(galleyObj)
      }
      let editAddFieldsDep=[];
     galleyItems&& galleyItems.map( (fieldValue, index) => {
      editAddFieldsDep.push({ key: fieldValue.customerId, name: fieldValue.name, value: fieldValue.name, label: fieldValue.name })
      return fieldValue;
      });
      setTrolleyItems(editAddFieldsDep);

      EditFormFields.map( editRow => {

      if (editRow.attribute === 'trolleyItem' ) {
      editRow.options = trolleyItems;
      }
      return editRow;
      });

  }
```